# Google Cloud SDK gcloud init

Tags: sdk, gcloud

I installed the Google Cloud SDK and Git, but when I try to run `gcloud init overseas-966` (my project name), I get this error message:

```
G:\>gcloud init overseas-966
WARNING: `gcloud init` will be changing soon. To clone git repo consider using `
gcloud alpha source clone` command.
Initialized gcloud directory in [G:\overseas-966\.gcloud].
Cloning [https://source.developers.google.com/p/overseas-966/r/default] into [de
fault].
ERROR: Unable to initialize project [overseas-966], cleaning up [G:\overseas-966
].
ERROR: (gcloud.init) Cannot find git. Please install git and try again.

You can find git installers at [http://git-scm.com/downloads], or use
your favorite package manager to install it on your computer.

G:\>git --version``
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
```

Git was downloaded from [http://git-scm.com/downloads] and the Git path is in the PATH environment variable. Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when gcloud tries to execute 'git', and for whatever reason it failed (not necessarily when git is not on the path).

Assuming you only care to clone the repo, you can achieve the same result by running

`git clone https://source.developers.google.com/p/overseas-966/r/default --config credential.helper=gcloud.cmd`

gcloud must be on your path for the above to work.

If issue persist please file a bug under https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list, with output of `gcloud info` (personal info removed).

Comment: I should add that my git version command also outputs 'git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1' and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue, but I had my project setup already.

Taken from [Google's Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes):

> **0.9.89 (2015/12/02)**
>
> gcloud Core
>
> - Changed behavior of `gcloud init` git repository clone option. It now takes as input a path to the destination directory for the repository, rather than the parent directory of the repository destination.

I think this is the change it is referring to. You can update your Cloud SDK components by running `gcloud components update`. Maybe updating your components will fix things.